# Keboard keys not working properly

Tags: keyboard, acer-aspire

I have a **Acer Aspire E1-431** ,

> I installed  windows 10 pro 32 bit

and i have installed big applications's(32 bit) like

- Visual Studio 2015,
- Sql 2012(Sequal server management studio)
- Adobe

and other application as well..

Then my keyboard not working properly...

> I need to press hard and some of keys are not working like (left shift
>   key, M key)..

How can i solve that?..Give me some suggestions. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Try with another keyboard could be easily a keyboard malfunction, if the incident persist go to: **Device management**.

To do that press the combination key of: **Win + r**, and write **devmgmt.msc**, (you will need to be connected to the internet) and reinstal the drivers related to usb.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply Man :) .. If i use another keyboard it works good..I need to travel with my laptop .. Using external keyboard is not satisfied..

Comment: Hey, If i uninstall all the applications , the keyboard works well.. I don't think its a hardware issue...